# How to find the Heron scheduler files when deployed it on Aurora and Mesos?

Tags: mesos, heron, apache-aurora

I can't find the `heron log files` when it was deployed on `Aurora and Mesos`. The `aurora-scheduler ui` showd as follows:
[image]

And In the `log-files` directory, there is no scheduler related log.
[image]
So do you have any ideas about this question? Where can I find the heron scheduler log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heron Aurora scheduler is executed on your local host when a topology is submitted. It prepares everything, update the state, and then invoke the `aurora` client. If you add `--verbose` to your submit command, you can see a lot of logs there. E.g.

``` [2018-06-28 09:42:35 -0700] [INFO] org.apache.heron.scheduler.aurora.AuroraLauncher: Launching topology in aurora 
...
...
[2018-06-28 09:42:35 -0700] [FINE] org.apache.heron.spi.utils.ShellUtils: Running synced process: ``aurora job create --wait-until RUNNING --bind ```

There's no log regarding the scheduling event saved once the topology starts to running inside aurora containers.